# how do I recover a missing file in azure devops

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

a code file is missing from my repository and in visual studio I get the error "the item does not exist in the project director it might have been moved renamed or deleted"  How can I recover the fileA?

Comment: Check if the file exists in previous commits and if yes, checkout the file at a given commit in the past to retrieve it.

Comment: Hi, Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a remind of [accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: thanks, I ended up just finding the file on an older server that was disconnected to the repo

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted the fileA, the ways to restore a deleted file depends on how convinced you were at the time you really wanted the file to be deleted.

1 deleted a file but didn’t commit

```
git checkout HEAD <filename>
```

This will work regardless of whether the deletion was staged or not.
2 deleted a file and committed the deletion

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

3 committed the deletion and then did more commits

(1) check the history for the deleted file and get the commit hash

```
git log -- <filename>
```

For example:

[image: git log]

(2) You can either work with the last commit that still had the file, or the commit that deleted the file

```
git checkout <commit hash> -- <filename>
```

```
git checkout <deletion commit hash>~1 -- <filename>
```

4 deleted a file ,committed and pushed

```
git revert --no-commit <commit>
```

If you rename the fileA to a new name, please rename it to original name.

Comment: @Tom McDonald Does it work for you?  If it helps, just a remind of accept an answer, this will help other users who has the same issue.

Comment: I ended up finding the file on an older server.  I'd try your solution, but probably wouldn't try it on an important repo as it seems to do some irreversible changes, is that the case?